# Boost Folder Missing from the Repo, what has changed?

Tags: c++, boost, build, include

I had an old version of boost and it was working fine. But now there is no boost folder in the repo? What is the include path and where are the .hpp files please?

The [Repo Link](https://github.com/boostorg/boost).

Comment: It looks like you need to use CMake to build the binaries.

Comment: But Boost is header only? Which binaries? I am suspecting I can't add boost recursivly as submodule? I am not sure. Could you please explain what you mean by building?

Comment: ***But Boost is header only?*** Some of boost is header only but it still contains many libraries that need to be compiled. I have 224 library files in my boost lib folder for an older version of boost. It takes about 20+ minutes to build.

Comment: How can I build the binaries then please? I am just surprised the .hpp files are not there? It's weird, it sounds like I am not cloning the whole thing. The hpp have nothing to do with the build no? (there is no .in too)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the version of boost you had previously was the release archive. This is the recommended and supported way to use Boost¹.

The release archives can be downloaded here: https://www.boost.org/users/download/ - they include what you expect.

#### What about Github?

The github repository is *NOT* a release archive. Instead it is a "super-project" that you can recursively clone to get all constituent libraries.

The headers are not part of the super - project (obviously, because they belong to the constituent libraries). If you want to do "modular boost" you should "build" the headers, which effectively links (or copies) the headers from the subprojects into the main include folder.

The build instructions for non-header only libraries are here:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/more/getting_started/index.html

---

¹ other projects might support other ways, like biicode, conan, vcpkg even Debian's `apt install libboost-all-dev` of course

Comment: Thanks very much. I did build the binaries :) and it works now!